# nfs mount causes freeze in terminal (after suspend?)

Tags: mount, 15.10, fstab, nfs

Running Ubuntu 15.10 desktop. Mounted up some folders with NFS4 from a Synology diskstation using fstab. This is example line in fstab file:

```
x.x.x.x:/volume1/projects /home/x/Projects nfs auto 0 0
```

(x are obviously just placeholders here...)

I've experienced a couple of times now that after suspending the system overnight, and then running a gnome-terminal and try e.g. "ls" or even "ls a"+tab (for tab completion) the terminal window freezes.
Reading up on NFS mounting, I see that this sounds like it's due to the default 'hard' NFS mount option.
I have tried to just suspend and wake the system up again without seeing this issue, so I suspect it is some kind of timeout occuring during the overnight suspend.
The target NFS server system (Synology) is online the whole time.
The last time this happened I could start new terminals and kill frozen "ls" processes to get back control. But a new "ls" command would freeze it again, and after a little bit of this, the whole system (except the mouse pointer) froze up on me.

Q's:

1) Is it as I suspect the NFS hard mount that is causing this? (I'm rewriting to soft links in the fstab file now to see if that helps.)

2) Would this possibly behave differently with autofs, even with hard mounts?

3) Is it as I suspect some timeout on either the NFS server or client side that occurs? (And why is this not restored at wakeup of the client?)

4) Is there any way to "refresh" a timed-out NFS mount, after wakeup?

5) Is it logical that a terminal freezes during "ls" when the current folder is not any of the NFS mounted folders, or even in fact not having any NFS mount files/folders open in any programs?

If you've read this far, thanx for the attention :o)

Comment: Rewriting to soft mounts did not help. :(

Comment: A little correction on Q 5) above: 'ls' only hangs in folders which includes mounted folders. If I go to say the root folder, 'ls' works fine.

Comment: I'm currently fighting with this exact problem. If you managed to solve it since 2016, would you please post your solution as the answer to your own question?